# Determine which numbers in list add up to specified value

Tags: python, math, sum

I have a quick (hopefully accounting problem. I just entered a new job and the books are a bit of a mess. The books have these lump sums logged, while the bank account lists each and every individual deposit. I need to determine which deposits belong to each lump sum in the books. So, I have these four lump sums:

[6884.41, 14382.14, 2988.11, 8501.60]

I then have this larger list of individual deposits (sorted):

[98.56, 98.56, 98.56, 129.44, 160.0, 242.19, 286.87, 290.0, 351.01, 665.0, 675.0, 675.0, 677.45, 677.45, 695.0, 695.0, 695.0, 695.0, 715.0, 720.0, 725.0, 730.0, 745.0, 745.0, 750.0, 750.0, 750.0, 750.0, 758.93, 758.93, 763.85, 765.0, 780.0, 781.34, 781.7, 813.79, 824.97, 827.05, 856.28, 874.08, 874.44, 1498.11, 1580.0, 1600.0, 1600.0]

In Python, how can I determine which sub-set of the longer list sums to one of the lump sum values?
(NOTE: these numbers have the additional problem that the sum of the lump sums is $732.70 more than the sum of the individual accounts. I'm hoping that this doesn't make this problem completely unsolvable)

Comment: What is your level of experience with Python?  Is this an accounting problem or a programming question?

Comment: I have a decent amount of familiarity with Python, but my math skills are rusty. So, this is more of an accounting problem.

Comment: If you just brute-force this there's no guarantee that you won't get a false set of individual deposits summed up to a lump. You could try to fish out all possible combinations, but then which is the true one? Without identification this problem might just be unsolvable.

Comment: Supposing that they happen to generate only one possible combo each, how would I even brute-force this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty good start at a solution:

```
import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby
from math import ceil

def _unique_subsets_which_sum_to(target, value_counts, max_sums, index):
    value, count = value_counts[index]
    if index:
        # more values to be considered; solve recursively
        index -= 1
        rem = max_sums[index]

        # find the minimum amount that this value must provide,
        # and the minimum occurrences that will satisfy that value
        if target <= rem:
            min_k = 0
        else:
            min_k = (target - rem + value - 1) // value  # rounded up to next int

        # find the maximum occurrences of this value
        # which result in <= target
        max_k = min(count, target // value)

        # iterate across min..max occurrences
        for k in range(min_k, max_k+1):
            new_target = target - k*value
            if new_target:
                # recurse
                for solution in _unique_subsets_which_sum_to(new_target, value_counts, max_sums, index):
                    yield ((solution + [(value, k)]) if k else solution)
            else:
                # perfect solution, no need to recurse further
                yield [(value, k)]
    else:
        # this must finish the solution
        if target % value == 0:
            yield [(value, target // value)]

def find_subsets_which_sum_to(target, values):
    """
    Find all unique subsets of values which sum to target

        target   integer >= 0, total to be summed to
        values   sequence of integer > 0, possible components of sum
    """
    # this function is basically a shell which prepares
    #  the input values for the recursive solution

    # turn sequence into sorted list
    values = sorted(values)
    value_sum = sum(values)

    if value_sum >= target:
        # count how many times each value appears
        value_counts = [(value, len(list(it))) for value,it in groupby(values)]

        # running total to each position
        total = 0
        max_sums = [0]
        for val,num in value_counts:
            total += val * num
            max_sums.append(total)

        start = dt.datetime.utcnow()
        for sol in _unique_subsets_which_sum_to(target, value_counts, max_sums, len(value_counts) - 1):
            yield sol
        end = dt.datetime.utcnow()
        elapsed = end - start
        seconds = elapsed.days * 86400 + elapsed.seconds + elapsed.microseconds * 0.000001
        print("  -> took {:0.1f} seconds.".format(seconds))

# I multiplied each value by 100 so that we can operate on integers
# instead of floating-point; this will eliminate any rounding errors.
values = [
    9856, 9856, 9856, 12944, 16000, 24219, 28687, 29000, 35101, 66500,
    67500, 67500, 67745, 67745, 69500, 69500, 69500, 69500, 71500, 72000,
    72500, 73000, 74500, 74500, 75000, 75000, 75000, 75000, 75893, 75893,
    76385, 76500, 78000, 78134, 78170, 81379, 82497, 82705, 85628, 87408,
    87444, 149811, 158000, 160000, 160000
]
sum_to = [
    298811,
    688441,
    850160  #,
            # 1438214
]

def main():
    subset_sums_to = []
    for target in sum_to:
        print("\nSolutions which sum to {}".format(target))
        res = list(find_subsets_which_sum_to(target, values))
        print("  {} solutions found".format(len(res)))
        subset_sums_to.append(res)
    return subset_sums_to

if __name__=="__main__":
    subsetsA, subsetsB, subsetsC = main()
```

which on my machine results in

```
Solutions which sum to 298811
  -> took 0.1 seconds.
  2 solutions found

Solutions which sum to 688441
  -> took 89.8 seconds.
  1727 solutions found

Solutions which sum to 850160
  -> took 454.0 seconds.
  6578 solutions found

# Solutions which sum to 1438214
#   -> took 7225.2 seconds.
#   87215 solutions found
```

The next step is to cross-compare solution subsets and see which ones can coexist together. I think the fastest approach would be to store subsets for the smallest three lump sums, iterate through them and (for compatible combinations) find the remaining values and plug them into the solver for the last lump sum.

---

Continuing from where I left off (+ a few changes to the above code to grab the return lists for subsums to the first three values).

I wanted a way to easily get the remaining value-coefficients each time;

```
class NoNegativesDict(dict):
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if set(other) - set(self):
            raise ValueError
        else:
            res = NoNegativesDict()
            for key,sv in self.iteritems():
                ov = other.get(key, 0)
                if sv < ov:
                    raise ValueError
                # elif sv == ov:
                #     pass
                elif sv > ov:
                    res[key] = sv - ov
            return res
```

then I apply it as

```
value_counts = [(value, len(list(it))) for value,it in groupby(values)]
vc = NoNegativesDict(value_counts)
nna = [NoNegativesDict(a) for a in subsetsA]
nnb = [NoNegativesDict(b) for b in subsetsB]
nnc = [NoNegativesDict(c) for c in subsetsC]

# this is kind of ugly; with some more effort
# I could probably make it a recursive call also
b_tries = 0
c_tries = 0
sol_count = 0
start = dt.datetime.utcnow()

for a in nna:
    try:
        res_a = vc - a
        sa = str(a)

        for b in nnb:
            try:
                res_b = res_a - b
                b_tries += 1
                sb = str(b)

                for c in nnc:
                    try:
                        res_c = res_b - c
                        c_tries += 1

                        #unpack remaining values
                        res_values = [val for val,num in res_c.items() for i in range(num)]
                        for sol in find_subsets_which_sum_to(1438214, res_values):
                            sol_count += 1
                            print("\n================")
                            print("a =", sa)
                            print("b =", sb)
                            print("c =", str(c))
                            print("d =", str(sol))

                    except ValueError:
                        pass

            except ValueError:
                pass

    except ValueError:
        pass

print("{} solutions found in {} b-tries and {} c-tries".format(sol_count, b_tries, c_tries))
end = dt.datetime.utcnow()
elapsed = end - start
seconds = elapsed.days * 86400 + elapsed.seconds + elapsed.microseconds * 0.000001
print("  -> took {:0.1f} seconds.".format(seconds))
```

and the final output:

```
0 solutions found in 1678 b-tries and 93098 c-tries
  -> took 73.0 seconds.
```

So the final answer is **there is no solution for your given data**.

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: It does. Although there is no answer, the math and logic is *beautiful*. Thank you.